# How to set a audio file as the devices ringtone or save it on the device?

Tags: java, android, audio, environment-variables, outputstream

I'm trying for many hours now to set a Ringtone on my device, which I saved in my android studio project at R.raw.myringtone.

I read that I firstly have to save it on the device, but this didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
InputStream in=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myringtone);
try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "myringtone.mp3"));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And if I can solve this problem how can I set the file programmatically as my ringtone?